# Re-order bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to re-order bootstrap columns for the desktop version of my web page.

Please see image below.

The columns don't have a fixed height.

Column B is higher than A and C on the desktop version because of larger content.

Basically, I want to "merge" column A and C on the desktop version.

I want to avoid using duplicate HTML (show/hide) or jQuery to "cut and paste" the element depending on browser size.

Any ideas how to achieve this with CSS?

Thanks!

---

Mobile version:

```
<div class="column-A col-xs-12">
     ...
</div>

<div class="column-B col-xs-12">
    ...
</div>

<div class="column-C col-xs-12">
     ...
</div>
```

Desktop version:

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: You cannot modify the structure of your markup with media queries alone, but you can affect their presentation. Flexbox is currently the best way to rearrange things visually without having to modify markup.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Did you tried `Bootstrap Push And Pull` classes??

Comment: Thanks. I haven't managed to find a solution. I updated my question to better illustrate what I am looking for. Hopefully, there's a solution with Column Ordering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question. This is possible by using Pull and Push classes in bootstrap. Bootstrap calls is Column Ordering. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering )

So, basic fundamental is that first you order the HTML to the way you want it to appear on your mobile and then for the desktop, you push the first element to the right and at the same time pull the second element to the left. This will give you the desired output.

Following is how you would code it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Try it out, if you face any issues, post it in comments and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't managed to find a solution. I updated my question to better illustrate what I am looking for. Hopefully, there's a solution with Column Ordering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input! I found a solution that is 90% satisfying.

There is still a problem if the content of column A is higher than column B., In that case, column C cannot be pulled to the right because it is stuck on column A.

Any ideas on how to get around that? Thanks.

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pull-md-left {
    float: left;
  }

  .pull-md-right {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="column-A col-sm-12 col-md-4 pull-md-right">
    ...
</div>

<div class="column-B col-sm-12 col-md-8 pull-md-left">
    ...
</div>

<div class="column-C col-sm-12 col-md-4 pull-md-right">
    ...
</div>
```